Every graph with a unique vertex of maximum degree is Class 1
Let $G$ be graph such that there is a unique vertex $v \in V(G)$ of maximum degree $\Delta(G)$. Prove that $\chi'(G) = \Delta(G)$ where $\chi'(G)$ is the chromatic index of $G$, i.e., the minimum required number of colors for the edges of $G$.
I have considered a $\Delta(G)+1$ edge-coloring of the graph and then tried to re-color it only using $\Delta(G)$ as we for example know there is a color that $v$ does not use to color its edges, and every other vertex omits at least two colors for coloring their edges. However, I was not able to come up with a sophisticated solution and feel stucked. Any help/hint for a solution is appreciated.
